# Apache first blank space break

Tags: php, apache, url-encoding

I have some strange problem on my Apache shared host server.

I have embedded devices that send GET url:
(From row log file)

> "GET
>   /sensors/saveDataToDataBase?TEMPERATURESENSOR1=N&HUMIDITYSENSOR1=N&SERIALNOSENSOR1=9&RSSI=-53&SSID=FRITZ!Box
>   6360
>   Cable&IP=192.168.178.32&TEMPERATURESENSOR2=N&HUMIDITYSENSOR2=N&SERIALNOSENSOR2=10 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Logger"

When I try to get: REQUEST_URI with php

I just get:

> /sensors/saveDataToDataBase?TEMPERATURESENSOR1=N&HUMIDITYSENSOR1=N&SERIALNOSENSOR1=9&RSSI=-53&SSID=FRITZ!Box

The url break after first blank space.

Is there any solution to my problem?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I typically look at `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`.  Do those values provide the full request?  Looks like non URL encoded space (%20) is causing it to truncate? Not sure I've seen that. Easy fix if you can control what is sent would be to URL encode the query string. Would `php://input` offer more? Got me curious...

Comment: Maybe use of mod_rewrite with a RewriteMap?

Comment: I would argue that the link is invalid. Your spaces should be encoded (`%20`). [RFC1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) mentions spaces as "unsafe".

Comment: Same problem with $_REQUEST Array
(
    [TEMPERATURESENSOR1] => 5.90
    [HUMIDITYSENSOR1] => 85.0
    [SERIALNOSENSOR1] => 9
    [RSSI] => -66
    [SSID] => FRITZ!Box
)